# Grunt required github token during docker build

Tags: github, gruntjs, docker, github-api, volojs

Grunt requires a github authentication token while it is executed during a docker build for an image. How do I provide grunt with the required token? Interactive passing doesn't work (as I already exacted).

The message of grunt is:

```
Running "volo:add:-nostamp:twbs/bootstrap/3.3.2:packages/bootstrap/" (volo) task
GitHub auth required for api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/tags: {"message":"API rate limit exceeded for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"}
GitHub access token required to complete action. In a web browser, go to:

https://github.com/settings/tokens

and generate a new "Personal access token" for volo. Only "repo" and "public_repo" permissions are needed. Paste the generated token below.
GitHub Personal Access Token:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL of the repository to:

```
https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyApp/myapp.git
```

More informations at: https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-a-docker-container-to-automatically-pull-from-github-using-oauth/